# Why can't i get my submit button working? or something else is off?

Tags: php, submit

i can't get my submit button working or something else is off?
here's my code for submit.

what im trying to do is to search from the drop down list menu and display all the details of the item i selected on the drop down list menu.

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
    {

        if($_POST['Submit'] == "Search" )
        {

            $sql = "SELECT tbl_item.*, tbl_ingredient.brandname, tbl_misc.size , tbl_misc.color
                    FROM (tbl_item LEFT JOIN tbl_ingredient ON tbl_item.itemid = tbl_ingredient.itemid) LEFT JOIN tbl_misc ON tbl_item.itemid = tbl_misc.itemid Where tbl_item.itemid = ". $_POST['Item'];
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<table width='990' height='69' border='1' align='center' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo  "<td width='150' height='23'><div align='center'>Item Name</div></td>";
        echo   "<td width='153'><div align='center'>High Quantity Threshold</div></td>";
        echo   "<td width='151'><div align='center'>Low Quantity Threshold</div></td>";
        echo   "<td width='127'><div align='center'>Quantity per unit</div></td>";
        echo   "<td width='72'><div align='center'>Item Type</div></td>";
        echo   "<td width='37'><div align='center'>Description</div></td>";
        echo   "<td width='94'><div align='center'>Brand Name</div></td>";
        echo   "<td width='90'><div align='center'>Size</div></td>";
        echo   "<td width='100'><div align='center'>Color</div></td>";
        echo   "<td width='100'><div align='center'>Action</div></td>";
        echo   "</tr>";

        $holder = pg_query($sql);
        $col = 0;
 while ($row = pg_fetch_array($holder, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC))
        {               
        $itemname = $row['itemname'];
        $highqntythreshold = $row['highqntythreshold'];
        $lowqntythreshold = $row['lowqntythreshold'];
        $qpunit = $row['qntyperunit'];
        $itemtype = $row['itemtype'];
        $description = $row['description'];
        $brandname = $row['brandname'];
        $size = $row['size'];
        $color = $row['color'];

    echo "<tr align='center' bgcolor = ''>";
    echo "<td height='23'>".$itemname."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$highqntythreshold."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$lowqntythreshold."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$unit."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$itemtype."</td>";
    echo "<td>".number_format($price,2)."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$brandname."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$size."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$color."</td>";
    echo "<td>.Edit</td>";            
    echo "</tr>";

        }
    }
```

thanks!.

Comment: where is your form code ?

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: do you still have the error?

Comment: oh...darn i know something is off :) thanks.. can u teach me on how to use `<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>`?
i want to make it like updating and item details thing where when u press the link Edit `echo "<td><a href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" Edit</a></td>"; ` it will include(tableforupdate.php) so i can throw there all the date i need to update.? im not sure if i explain it well.